# laravel 5.2 redirect to url with parameters

Tags: redirect, laravel-5

hi everyone :) i develop the form that get data from users and search with amazon api then i want to show results in another page , i just redirect to another page with my result parameters , but i cannot access to my parameters in new page , here is my code

```
            $search = new Search();
            $search->setCategory('Books');
            $search->setKeywords($searchItem);
            $search->setPage(2);
            $search->setResponseGroup(array('Large'));

            $response = $apaiIO->runOperation($search);


            $totalResult = $response['Items']['TotalResults'];
            $totalPage = $response['Items']['TotalPages'];

            $data = array(
                'response' => $response,
                'totalResult' => $totalResult,
                'totalPage' => $totalPage,
                'uni' => $unies,
            );


            return redirect('/searchItem')->with($data);
```

please help me to solve my problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use `with()` in your redirect, you can access the `$data` array using:

```
{{ session('response') }}
```

or:

```
Session::get('response')
```

Note that the data sent with `with()` is flash data, which means it will be deleted on page refresh or navigation.

If you want to add the array to the URL, you can do:

```
redirect('/searchItem?'. http_build_query( $data ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods of redirect to blade file or function. You may try this :-

```
Redirect to blade file use this method:-
return view('your viewfile')->with(compact('data'));
                   or
Redirect to method in controller use this technique:-
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect; // Add this in top of controller
return Redirect::to('/searchItem')->with(compact('data'));
```

Hope it helps